# Regarding TCP SYN flood: Why is half-open connections worse than established connections?

Tags: tcp, ddos, denial-of-service

THIS IS NOT ASKED FOR HACKING PURPOSES. I am studying computer science and I am just curious.

So..
When the host A sends a TCP SYN to host B, host B allocates space for receiving buffer etc., sends a SYNACK back to host A and host A allocates such space as well, then sends an ACK back to host B. The connection is then established.

But why does a half-open connection (one where the last ACK from A is never sent) tear down host B more than a fully established connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A half-open connection does not take more resources than a fully opened connection and a bunch of them do not overwhelm a server more easily, quickly, or surely than fully opened connections.

But you only need to send one packet to a server to make it create a half-open connection, whereas you need to complete a TCP handshake (1 send, 1 receive, another send) to create a fully open connection. So you can create lots of half-open connections from a spoofed IP address or quickly generate millions of them from a DDoS platform. You don't have to be in a position to receive the `SYN|ACK` replies. You don't even have to care if the server is able to produce those replies fast enough.

This assumes absence of SYN cookies or other defenses against half-open connections.

Comment: Thanks alot! :)

So having a half-open or fully established connection is pretty much the same when it comes to overloading the server?
And the only reason we leave it half-open is because there's no reason sending the ACK from host A? (assuming we don't care if we use our own source IP, cus else the reason would be that we CAN'T)

So pretty much... half-open and fully-open connections take up the same amount of resources, but fully-open requires that we send another TCP segment?

Comment: Just to add a bit of info, half-open connections actually use fewer resources than fully-established connections. From https://lwn.net/Articles/277146/ : "Linux no longer uses all of the memory necessary for a full connection until the new connection is fully open. Instead it uses a "minisock" for that period. The minisock is a 96 byte struct tcp_request_sock structure holding the minimum state necessary to get the connection fully opened. The fully established struct tcp_sock is 1616 bytes. Both structure size measurements refer to a 64-bit kernel." This can help mitigate DOS attacks.